# Cassandra NAMED datacenter

Tags: cassandra

After a day of research, I open a question.

I can't rename a cassandra node. I would like to put a node at D1, and another one at D2 both in rack1.

But here is the result I get

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.0.1  185.58 KiB  256          100.0%            21d6f3db-79d3-4b3b-9fb8-7da42c82610e  rack1
UN  10.0.0.2  75.07 KiB  256          100.0%            2bb2e75e-23a6-4dc4-a279-ab28b739255d  rack1
```

Both nodes are in "datacenter1"
Here is my configuration on first device:

cassandra.yaml:

```
cluster_name: 'kban'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.0.0.2"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.0.0.1
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: 10.0.0.1
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: dc
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
back_pressure_enabled: false
back_pressure_strategy:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure
      parameters:
        - high_ratio: 0.90
          factor: 5
          flow: FAST
enable_materialized_views: true
enable_sasi_indexes: true
```

cassandra-rackdc.properties :

```
dc=D1
rack=RACK1
```

On second devices :

cassandra.yaml :

```
cluster_name: 'kban'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
cdc_enabled: false
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.0.0.1"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 10.0.0.2
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: 10.0.0.2
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: dc
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
back_pressure_enabled: false
back_pressure_strategy:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure
      parameters:
        - high_ratio: 0.90
          factor: 5
          flow: FAST
enable_materialized_views: true
enable_sasi_indexes: true
```

cassandra-rackdc.properties :

```
dc=D2
rack=RACK1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `SimpleSnitch`: `endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch` - it doesn't allow to have multiple DCs - all nodes are always in the `datacenter1`.

to put nodes into different DC, you need to change configuration to use `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` - after that it will pick the DC & rack name from `cassandra-rackdc.properties`. But as you can't easily change snitch after you initialized Cassandra, you'll need to remove Cassandra data directories, and perform initialization again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally succeeded! Command for reset Cassandra : `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/* /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_auth/* /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_distributed/* /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/*  /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_traces/* /var/log/cassandra/* /var/run/cassandra/*`